# PHP header(location:) redirect with root directory

Tags: php

Is there a way to create a  `header('Location:');` path that starts to the root directory.

Examples Like:

```
formaction="/cert/forms/sessions/session-inc-info.php"
```

or

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cert/forms/sessions/session-inc-info.php');
```

cert is my root directory folder

ive been trying codes like

```
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cert/forms/sessions/session-inc-info.php);
```

and

```
header('Location:/cert/forms/sessions/session-inc-info.php');
```

the only thing works for me is using `../`

```
header('Location:../../../session-inc-info.php');
```

but it's hard for me because i have alot of folders and subfolders.
and i have so many scripts that have to be redirected.

Thanks.

so this is the sample folder structure

[image]

so the `content.php` will have a button that redirects to the `session.php` and i have done that already and now when the `session.php` script will have a `header('Location:');` that must redirect to the dashboard.php . now that is my problem. i don't now how to create the path like

cert---->dashboard----->dashboard.php

Comment: Show folder structure from the root directory. @Vincent

Comment: @PassionInfinite ok... i will make a sample folder structure.

Comment: What is the name of the Main File - the Entry Point to your App? Something like the `index.php` or similar. And where does it live? Assuming it lives inside `CERT`, to redirect to `dashboard.php` from that location using relative paths, you could do: `header("Location: ./dashboard/dashboard.php")` The same goes for `session.php` or `content.php`. But aren't those Files not supposed to be helper Files rather that Files that would be exposed to the Public (displayed)?

Comment: Do You have any `htaccess` File in your Project as well?

Comment: i dont want to use `./` coz it's hard to keep track when im having many sub folders.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$formaction;
```

location should contain URL, not server file path

Comment: Thanks. it work. for me `header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/cert/forms/sessions/session-inc-info.php?id-inc='.$id);`

Answer (score 1):

> You could ***theoretically*** create a PHP File at the Root of your Application and call it anything you like: say `redirect.php`. Then inside of this `redirect.php`, you could put some code that might look something like this:

```
<?php
    // CREATE AN ARRAY THAT WITH NUMERIC KEY
    // THAT WILL CORRESPOND TO THE FILE YOU WISH TO REDIRECT TO (ACTUALLY LOAD)
    // SINCE THIS IS A PSEUDO REDIRECT:
    $fileMap            = array(
        0   => "./file-1.php",
        1   => "./file-2.php",
        2   => "./file-3.php",
        3   => "./file-4.php",
        4   => "./file-5.php",
        5   => "./file-6.php",
        6   => "/cert/forms/sessions/session-inc-info.php",
        7   => "./../../session-inc-info.php",  //<== YOU MAY KEEP ADDING TO LIST
    );

    // CHECK THAT THERE IS A GET PARAM WITH NAME: to
    if(isset($_GET['to'])){
        $fileKey        = $_GET['to'];          //<== GET THE `to` PARAM FROM $_GET
        $loadableFile   = $fileMap[$fileKey];   //<== TRANSLATE `to` KEY TO A LOADABLE FILE

        // IF THE FILE [$loadableFile] EXISTS, LOAD IT
        // OTHERWISE REDIRECT TO MAIN-APPLICATION PAGE (HOMEPAGE)
        if(file_exists($loadableFile)){
            require_once $loadableFile;
        }else{
            header("location: index.php");      //<== ASSUMES index.php IS THE MAIN FILE.
            exit;
        }
    }

    // IF ALL FAILS, STILL REDIRECT TO THE MAIN-APPLICATION PAGE
    header("location: index.php");              //<== ASSUMES index.php IS THE MAIN FILE.
```

> Then on each page where you wish to Perform a redirect, you may simply do something like this:

```
<?php
    // ASSUMING YOU WANT TO RE-DIRECT TO: `./../../session-inc-info.php`
    // AS YOU CAN SEE FROM THE `$fileMap` ARRAY, `./../../session-inc-info.php`
    // HAS THE KEY OF "7"
    // NOW ALL YOU CAN DO IS SIMPY APPEND "?to=7" TO `redirect.php` 
    // IN THE `header()` METHOD LIKE THIS:
    header("location: redirect.php?to=7"); 
    exit;
    /*EXPECTED TO LOAD THE FILE: `./../../session-inc-info.php`
```

> **NOTE:**
> *This is not really a Redirect (as it is basically  just loading[including] Files from a given Location/Path, however since it seems you are trying to load some file like: `/cert/forms/sessions/session-inc-info.php`, it is assumed that this may be an option.* **To do a real Redirect: just use the header() Function directly passing it the exact URL-Location to which to redirect.**

Cheers and Good-Luck...